# Eclipse client hangs when maximizing a view

Tags: eclipse, rtc, ibm-rad

In various eclipse clients (Rational Software Architect 8.0.3, Rational Team Concert, 4.0.2) when I try to maximize any view, it hangs my Windows 7 laptop for 2-3 minutes. Eventually it just finishes and returns control and I can continue as if nothing has happened, but the first time I maximize a view after restarting, this happens.

I would have thought it was a problem with that application, but since it happens it two different Eclipse clients (they are in separate installation directories) it seems like it is something common.

I can't do anything when the hang happens (process explorer will not come up, CTRL+ALT+DEL does not respond) so I can't tell what is hanging.

I have asked other members of my team and they haven't experienced this so I am hoping to find more ideas with a wider audience.

Comment: Is your laptop a Win7 32 or 64bits? Are your Rational clients 32 or 64 bits? Did you see a similar behavior on colleague's laptop? (note: I don't see it in my RTC4.0.3 based on Eclipse4.2 in my Win7 64 bits desktop)

Comment: Windows 7 is 64bit  16GB of memory Thinkpad W520. Both clients are 64bit installations as well. I am unable to upgrade to 4.0.3 right now since our server is 4.0.2.

Comment: I had issues with 64bits clients before, I ended up uninstalling everything (up to the "Installation Manager"), install the Installation Manager 32 bits, and install 32bits only clients (even though I am on a 64bits Win7). The end result felt more stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem with the Rational Publishing Engine (also Eclipse) and I fixed it by disabling animation in the `Preferences>General>Appearance` menu.

This screenshot is from a straight install of Eclipse but I am sure it is similar on the tools you have:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse Preferences]

Comment: Thanks so much. That appears to have fixed it.